# rvm cluttering up my environment vars

Tags: mac, bash, environment-variables, rvm

I was trying to see a list of my environment variables in Bash (Mac Terminal) by typing `set`. But when I do, I am overwhelmed by a bunch of functions apparently defined by RVM. Is this supposed to happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's normal . . . you can try and use grep to filter the results, e.g. `set | grep -v rvm`, though that won't help with the multi-line items.

Comment: Alternatively, `printenv` is probably better to use